# Editing only selected features in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

I've got a big features layer with more than 30 000 points. I want to edit some of them using the snap tool, but I'm afraid it's going to edit some points I don't want to be edited.

Is it possible to only edit selected features?

Comment: Another way would be to export the points you want to edit to a new feature class, delete them from the big fc, edit them with the snap tool and then merge the two together again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS tools, if there are selected records in the feature class,the tool will only work on those selected features.  That being said, the Snap tool is an editing tool which is making changes to the input data so back up your data before executing this tool on your selected records.